# Alternatives to VEDA 4 vibrational energy distribution analysis software?

Tags: software, vibrations, from-chem-se, psi4, gamess

Said software is useful when you need to assign the peaks in vibrational spectra to different vibrational modes found in a hessian calculation for a given molecule, as described in [Jamróz, Michał H. “Vibrational Energy Distribution Analysis (VEDA): Scopes and Limitations”. Spectrochimica Acta Part A: Molecular and Biomolecular Spectroscopy, vol. 114, outubro de 2013, p. 220–30. ScienceDirect, doi:10.1016/j.saa.2013.05.096.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1386142513005891) It's becoming popular, the paper has nearly 450 citations as of april 2020, but it has some downsides for me:

- Despite being a freeware that can be downloaded from [their site](https://smmg.pl/software/veda) by anyone, it's not [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition), or at least open source, and it's windows-only;
- Doesn't support people using free tools like [Gamess-US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAMESS_(US)) or [Psi4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSI_(computational_chemistry)), only accepting Gaussian output files as its input, a paid and very expensive quantum chemistry software;

So I did some research for alternatives that could avoid these downsides. Among the citations to the VEDA paper, I've found what seems to be a alternative approach to solve the same problem, as described in [Teixeira, Filipe, e M. Natália D. S. Cordeiro. “Improving Vibrational Mode Interpretation Using Bayesian Regression”. Journal of Chemical Theory and Computation, vol. 15, no 1, janeiro de 2019, p. 456–70. ACS Publications, doi:10.1021/acs.jctc.8b00439.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.8b00439) Their software, called vibAnalysis, is open source, and available from a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/teixeirafilipe/vibAnalysis). It doesn't support Gamess-US or Psi4, but at least supports [ORCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCA_(quantum_chemistry_program)), which is free for academics, besides Gaussian.

I wonder if there are other alternatives I have missed in my research, specially if they run on linux and work with Gamess-US or Psi4. If somebody here could provide some guidance, I'd be grateful. I posted [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/132170/89908) in chemistry.stackexchange at first, before materials.stackexchange entered beta. As it went unanswered, I'm giving it a try here.

Comment: PGOPHER is free and can be used to view vibrational peaks, but probably doesn't support GAMESS-US or Psi4. Would it be difficult to convert the GAMESS-US or Psi4 output into ORCA format?

Comment: Hi Ksousa / Nike,

You may be able to use the Molden software to read the Gamess-US software output and save the matrices into the Molden format. You then may be able to import the Molden format into PGOPHER; which can simulate and fit vibrational spectra.

http://cheminf.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/molden_format.html
http://pgopher.chm.bris.ac.uk/Help/index.htm
http://pgopher.chm.bris.ac.uk/Help/importlmatrix.htm

Comment: @SuStephens your comment will automatically notify the user who posted the question. To notify someone else of your comment (if they have already commented themselves), you can use `@username` as I did for this comment.

Comment: ksousa: Did you manage to solve this problem? Did the suggestion of Susana Stephens help? (i.e. use MOLDEN to convert the GAMESS-US output into MOLDEN format, then use PGOPHER to read the MOLDEN and and fit the vibrational spectral?). MOLDEN and PGOPHER are both free.

Comment: @NikeDattani , I still didn't test it.

Comment: Okay, let us know when you've tested it. If it works I'll tell Susana to turn the comment into an answer. Just trying to clear up the un-answered queue here. It's been posted on Twitter: https://twitter.com/StackMatter/status/1272710832749772801 You can re-tweet to get more attention, but Susana's answer might be correct.

Comment: 10 days later, still no progress? It's been posted on twitter, and bumped up to the top on May 20th and then again on June 15th. There's not much more we can do now! Maybe you can put a bounty on it after all that rep you earned from the O(N logN) question!

Comment: Did the suggestion of Susana Stephens work?

Comment: @NikeDattani, I still could not complete the full sequence proposed. I'm used to Avogadro as a GUI, and the Molden interface is a bit odd. Still figuring out how to use it.

Comment: 18 hours left in the grace period. I've written to @SuStephens on Messenger to remind her to try to turn the comment into an answer. You will still be able to award her the bounty, but you have to do it manually (the automated system won't award her the bounty if the answer comes during the grace period).

Comment: I'm so sorry it didn't work out. She saw my message on Messenger, but was unable to reply (perhaps too busy). I wish the bounty was more successful, but I hope this doesn't turn you away from issuing one on a different question in the future. This question might have just been to specialized for the very small and narrow user-base we currently have. Today we reached 1000 registered users, but hopefully 1 year from now we will have closer to 10,000, and situations like this will turn out happier.

Comment: @ksousa supposedly, a free service called [Vibalizer](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.20642) existed to do this and it could read GAMESS output. However, it was mainly web based and the site has gone down. There was also a downloadable version that could be installed in Linux, so maybe you could contact them and see if they are still offering it.

Comment: @ksousa the web version is actually still reachable through the Wayback Machine. The site must have gone down sometime after 2016. https://web.archive.org/web/20160316061428/http://www.compchem.org/vibalizer/

Comment: i have VEDA 4 previously downloaded which is showing some error now. Thats why I am searching another softwre to calculate the PED for the output from Gaussain software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### LocVib (part of MoViPac)

I have never used VEDA before, but according to the paper, it decomposes the normal modes into vibrations of atomic groups, bond stretching, bending or something else.  Something similar is **LocVib**, which localizes normal modes to localized vibrational modes by maximizing the "distances"  between vibrational modes and "atomic contribution" to a mode, like localization of molecular orbitals.

LocVib is not same as VEDA, and the operation is somehow more complex.  The user need to select a subset of all normal modes on their own and the localization would be done by the software, and finally localized modes, typically related to several atoms will be printed out, with derived frequencies from the normal modes.

The software is in Python 2 and the github page is https://github.com/chjacob-tubs/LocVib.  It is also part of [MoViPac](https://reiher.ethz.ch/software/movipac.html).